# Do these two Java generic methods accept the same data types?

Tags: java, generics, binary-search

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to learn about generics. I tried to implement a simple version of `binarySearch()` method that is also found in the `Collections` class. I looked up the method signature and it's something like this:

```java
public static <T> int binarySearch(List<? extends Comparable<? super T>> list, T key) {
  // definition
}
```

I was wondering if the method above still accepts the same data types if you were to change the method definition to this:

```java
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> int binarySearch(List<T> list, T key) {
  // definition
}
```

If not, what are the differences between the two? Thank you!

Comment: In the first, the list can have different things than the type of key. You cannot add to the list and key is not comparable.

Comment: @matt oh i see. So in the first one, the list can accept subclasses of T (not just T) as long as T implements Comparable<? super T> ?

Comment: Yes, you also have some semantic differences between List<? extends Z> vs List<Z>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider these classes:

```
class A extends Comparable<A> { /* ... */ }
class B extends A { /* ... */ }
```

Now define a key and a list with these types:

```
A key = new B();
List<B> list = List.of(key);
```

You can invoke  the first form with these arguments, but not the second.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm marking this as correct because this is easier for me to understand as a beginner. Both answers teach me something new today.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
static class NonComparable {

}

static class MyComparable implements Comparable<NonComparable> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(NonComparable o) {
        return 0; // irrelevant for the example
    }
}
```

And then declare the parameters:

```
List<MyComparable> list = Arrays.asList(new MyComparable());
NonComparable  nonComparable = new NonComparable();
binarySearch(list, nonComparable);
```

One of your method definitions allows an invocation, the other does not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it teaches me something new about Comparable today. I'll be doing more research on it